# Unable to update aws eks managed nodegroup to latest AMI Version using EKS Blueprints for terraform version 4.32.1

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

Getting this error when trying to update the eks nodegroup AMI version to a higher version than existing version using eks blueprints for terraform version 4.32.1:

> waiting for EKS Node Group (poc-ekscluster-xxx:terraform-eks-xxx-ng-2024020409403174960000000a) version update (c15d489f-74b3-3193-822d-08de0c8c089f): unexpected state 'Failed', wanted target 'Successful'. last error: : NodeCreationFailure: Couldn't proceed with upgrade process as new nodes are not joining node group

I was able to create the eks cluster with managed nodegroup without any issues successfully.

below is the main.tf details i used to create the cluster initially and for the nodegroup AMI Update process I have just replaced the release_version to a higher version like to "1.26.12-20240202" from "1.26.10-20231201"

Expectation is to resolve the eks managed nodegroup AMI Version update issue using same terraform eks blueprints version 4.32.1 only.

**main.tf**

```
module "eks_blueprints" {
 source = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints?ref=v4.32.1"
 cluster_name  = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.environment}" 
 cluster_version = var.eks_version
 vpc_id  = var.vpc_id
 private_subnet_ids = var.public_subnet_ids

 cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
 cluster_endpoint_public_access = true
    cluster_security_group_additional_rules = {
        rule1 = {
            type = "ingress"
            description = "Testing changes"
            from_port   = 0
            to_port     = 0
            protocol    = "-1"
            cidr_blocks = ["192.168.0.0/16"]
        }

    }

    node_security_group_additional_rules = {
 
        # Extend node-to-node security group rules. Recommended and required for the Add-ons
        ingress_self_all = {
            description = "Node to node all ports/protocols"
            protocol = "-1"
            from_port = 0
            to_port = 0
            type = "ingress"
            self = true
        }
        # Recommended outbound traffic for Node groups
        egress_all = {
            description = "Node all egress"
            protocol  = "-1"
            from_port = 0
            to_port = 0
            type  = "egress"
            cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
            ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
        }
        # Allows Control Plane Nodes to talk to Worker nodes on all ports.
        ingress_cluster_to_node_all_traffic = {
            description  = "Cluster API to Nodegroup all traffic"
            protocol = "-1"
            from_port  = 0
            to_port  = 0
            type = "ingress"
            source_cluster_security_group = true
        }
    }



    managed_node_groups = {
        core_app = {
            node_group_name = "terraform-eks-${var.environment}-ng"
            instance_types = ["t3.medium"]
            ami_type       = "AL2_x86_64"
            release_version = "1.26.12-20240202"
            force_update_version = true
            capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
            disk_size      = 10
            subnet_ids = var.public_subnet_ids
            iam_role_attach_cni_policy = true
            attach_vpc_cni_policy = true
            vpc_cni_enable_ipv4 = true
            k8s_labels = {
                test-eks-node = "terraform-eks-${var.environment}-app"
            }
            tags = {
                Name        = "test"
                subnet_type = "private_test1"
            }
            #enable_monitoring = true
            public_ip = false
            pre_userdata = <<-EOT
                yum install -y amazon-ssm-agent
                systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent && systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
            EOT
            desired_size = 1
            max_size = 3
            min_size = 1
        }
    }

}



module "eks_blueprints_kubernetes_addons" {
    source  = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints//modules/kubernetes-addons?ref=v4.32.1"
    eks_cluster_id  = module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_id
    eks_cluster_endpoint  = module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_endpoint
    eks_oidc_provider = module.eks_blueprints.oidc_provider
    eks_cluster_version = module.eks_blueprints.eks_cluster_version
    eks_worker_security_group_id = module.eks_blueprints.worker_node_security_group_id
    auto_scaling_group_names  = module.eks_blueprints.self_managed_node_group_autoscaling_groups
 # AWS EKS Addons (AWS Managed Addons)
    enable_amazon_eks_vpc_cni = true
    amazon_eks_vpc_cni_config = {
        most_recent = true
    }
    enable_amazon_eks_coredns = true
    amazon_eks_coredns_config = {
        most_recent = true 
    }
    enable_amazon_eks_kube_proxy  = true
    amazon_eks_kube_proxy_config = {
        most_recent = true
    }
    enable_amazon_eks_aws_ebs_csi_driver = true
    amazon_eks_aws_ebs_csi_driver_config = {
        most_recent = true
    }
 # EKS Blueprints Addons (Deployed as Helm Charts from EKS Blueprints)
    enable_aws_load_balancer_controller = true
    enable_argocd = false
    enable_cert_manager  = true
    enable_cluster_autoscaler  = true
    depends_on = [
        module.eks_blueprints.managed_node_groups
    ]

}
```